# Segmentation fault when creating a new cyclical interlinked list

Tags: c, linked-list, c99

I'm trying to implement a cyclical interlinked list. However I receive a `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` message when I try to run my program.

I have a simple `list.h` file where I define all my `structs` and `functions`.

```
/**
 * @brief  defines a cyclical interlinked list
 */
typedef struct node {
    int          number;  // save a number for learning purpose
    struct node *next;    // pointer to the next node in the list
} node_t;

/**
 * @brief  defines a variable for the cyclical interlinked list
 *         -> this is the only known element
 */
static node_t *person_list;
    
/**
 * @brief Constructor
 */
void list_new();
```

This I then have implemented in my `list.c` file.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "list.h"

void list_new() {
    node_t *pointer = malloc(sizeof(node_t));
    
    if (pointer == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: failed to allocate a new list");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    
    person_list->next = pointer;
    
    if (person_list == person_list->next) {
        printf("It works.");
    }   
}
```

However, my call `list_new()` doesn't seem to work.

```
#include "list.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    list_new();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I know that a `segmentation fault` is a specific error that is being caused when trying to access memory that "does not belong to you". But I don't know where I am trying to access memory that does not belong to me.

My assumption is, that I'm doing something wrong with the static variable `person_list` but I don't know what.

Can you tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dereferenced `person_list` without assigning a valid pointer to that.

Example fix:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "list.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    person_list = malloc(sizeof(*person_list)); /* allocate and assign valid pointer */
    if (person_list == NULL) return 1; /* check if allocation is successful */

    list_new();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```